# Unable to resolve action

Tags: github-actions

I have the following GitHub action:

```
name: action-name

on: workflow_dispatch

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - uses: actions/setup-evaluation@v4
        with:
          python-version: '3.11'
```

A couple of days ago, the **Set up job** worked fine:

```
Current runner version: '2.311.0'
Operating System
  Ubuntu
  22.04.3
  LTS
Runner Image
  Image: ubuntu-22.04
  Version: 20231030.2.0
  Included Software: https://github.com/actions/runner-images/blob/ubuntu22/20231030.2/images/linux/Ubuntu2204-Readme.md
  Image Release: https://github.com/actions/runner-images/releases/tag/ubuntu22%2F20231030.2
Runner Image Provisioner
  2.0.312.1
GITHUB_TOKEN Permissions
  Contents: read
  Metadata: read
  Packages: read
Secret source: Actions
Prepare workflow directory
Prepare all required actions
Getting action download info
Download action repository 'actions/checkout@v3' (SHA:f43a0e5ff2bd294095638e18286ca9a3d1956744)
Download action repository 'actions/setup-python@v4' (SHA:65d7f2d534ac1bc67fcd62888c5f4f3d2cb2b236)
Complete job name: build
```

Now, I get:

```
Current runner version: '2.311.0'
Operating System
  Ubuntu
  22.04.3
  LTS
Runner Image
  Image: ubuntu-22.04
  Version: 20231115.7.0
  Included Software: https://github.com/actions/runner-images/blob/ubuntu22/20231115.7/images/ubuntu/Ubuntu2204-Readme.md
  Image Release: https://github.com/actions/runner-images/releases/tag/ubuntu22%2F20231115.7
Runner Image Provisioner
  2.0.312.1
GITHUB_TOKEN Permissions
  Contents: read
  Metadata: read
  Packages: read
Secret source: Actions
Prepare workflow directory
Prepare all required actions
Getting action download info
Error: Unable to resolve action actions/setup-evaluation, repository not found
```

The only thing that seems to change is the version, but I am unsure why it stopped working. Can I somewhat degrade it back to previous version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like this `actions/setup-evaluation@v4` repository does not exist any more in the [marketplace](https://github.com/marketplace?category=&type=actions&verification=&query=actions%2Fsetup-evaluation%40v4).

Instead you can use: `actions/setup-python@v4` since `actions/setup-evaluation@v4` used this action under the hood based on your logs. Here is the [link](https://github.com/actions/setup-python)

```yaml
name: action-name

on: workflow_dispatch

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v4
      - uses: actions/setup-python@v4
        with:
          python-version: '3.11'
```